# Python re.search exact match on variable

Tags: python, variables, pattern-matching

The contents of `iplist.txt` are in this format:

```
CART    6385    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
CART    3854    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
CART     385    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
```

I need help getting the python script below to only match `385` and print the results.

My code:

```
IPList = open('iplist.txt','r')    
CartID = raw_input('What is the Cart ID? ')

for line in IPList:            
    if re.search(CartID, line):
        print line.strip()
```

Output:

```
What is the Cart ID? 385
CART    6385    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
CART    3854    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
CART     385    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
```

I just need it to match `CART 385`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the word boundary `\b` sequence or the whitespace `\s` sequence to restrict the matched lines,

```
re.match(r'^\S+\s+\b%s\b' % CartID, line)
```

At the end, you'll have:

```
^    # At the start of the line
\S+  # Match one or more non-blank chars
\s+  # Match one or more whitespace chars
\b   # Word boundary
%s   # The replaced CartID
\b   # Word boundary (i.e. followed by whitespace)
```

Comment: What is the Cart ID? 385
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RQ.py", line 11, in <module>
    if re.match(r'^\S+\s\+\b%d\b' % CartID, line):
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: @gineraso, Sorry I overlooked the fact that it was a string, using `%s` instead

Comment: No worries.  With the %s I get no results for either pattern.

Comment: Sorry, an extra "\" before "+". Now the pattern is corrected.

Comment: Using this I get no results:  if re.match(r'^\S+\s\+\b%s\b' % CartID, line):

Comment: There shouldn't be any backslash before the plus signs (+). `"\+"` is a literal plus char, the `"+"` is a one or more operator. That is fixed in the answer already

Answer (score 4):

Use `re.match` instead of `search` to only match the start of the line and then use regex metacharacters to bracket the number you are looking for. In your case, the line starts with `"CART"` and you can use `"\s+"` (matching all whitespace so that you don't get something like 3385) to bracket.

```
import os
import re

# todo: debug - generate test file
if not os.path.exists('iplist.txt'):
    open('iplist.txt', 'w').write("""CART    6385    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
CART    3854    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10
CART     385    Cell IP: 10.10.10.10""")

CartID = raw_input('What is the Cart ID? ')

with open('iplist.txt') as IPList:
    for line in IPList:
         if re.match(r"CART\s+{}\s".format(CartID), line):
                print line.strip()
```

Comment: I don't see re.match in your example.

Comment: @gineraso - I pasted the wrong version of the code - fixed.

Comment: What is the Cart ID? 385
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RQ.py", line 12, in <module>
    if re.match(r"CART \s+{}\s".format(CartID), line):
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: You must be using an old version of python that requires a more verbose format string. Use `r"CART \s+{0}\s".format(CartID)"` (added a zero in the brackets) instead.

Comment: Yes,  I'm using 2.6.6.  After adding a zero in the brackets there is still no results for any input.

Comment: Hmmm... the example works. I had an extra space in the regex ("CART ..." instead of "CART\s+...") which would matter if the real data has tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: Yes.  Removing the extra space corrected the problem.  Thank you.